# run jquery function on element. what is wrong with this code?

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-selectors

What is wrong with this code?

```
$(function() {
    function testfunction() { $(this).addClass('testing');}
    $('.tester').testfunction();
});
```

Comment: That's not how you make a jQuery plugin. Right now you're just creating a normal JavaScript function. That doesn't make jQuery aware of it.

Comment: @K Ivanov: Extend the jQuery object with custom functionality, from the looks of it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`testfunction()` is not added to the jQuery function stack.**

If you want to be able to call it on an arbitrary object, you should add it to the jQuery function stack:

```
$.fn.testfunction = function() {
   this.addClass('testing');
};

$('.tester').testfunction(); // success!
```

You should take a look at jQuery's [Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) page for more information on how to properly write plugins.

Comment: Thanks. How do use variables that increment on every eliment the function is applied to? for example:

$.fn.testfunction = function() {
   incrementthis++;
   this.append(incrementthis);
   this.addClass('testing');
};

$('.tester').testfunction(); // success!

Comment: You should use `this.each(function() {});` inside the function. For more info, I *really* encourage you to read the http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring page. It will help you understand the subject better.